# Why is vroom so slow?

Tags: r, tidyverse, vroom

I have a simple operation where I read several csvs, bind them, and then export, but `vroom` is performing much slower than other methods. I must be doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what, or why.

```r
library(readr)
library(vroom)
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

write_csv(mtcars, "test.csv")

microbenchmark(
  readr={
    t <- read_csv("test.csv", col_types=cols())
    write_csv(t, "test.csv")
  },data.tabl={
    t <- fread("test.csv")
    fwrite(t, "test.csv", sep=",")
  },vroom={
    t <- vroom("test.csv", delim=",", show_col_types = F)
    vroom_write(t, "test.csv", delim=",")
  },
  times=10
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>       expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq        max neval
#>      readr 12.636961 12.662955 15.865400 12.928211 13.503029  41.104583    10
#>  data.tabl  2.200815  2.275252  2.633456  2.342797  2.529283   4.830134    10
#>      vroom 57.376353 57.915135 64.280365 58.496847 58.966311 117.150837    10
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I don't know, but is there any reason to expect vroom to be faster on **small** data sets?

Comment: I feel like this question would garner fewer negative reactions if it were worded less derogatorily toward the package `vroom` and more in the vein of trying to understand why one's own technique is bottlenecked...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do a test with more data, I used the CSV from https://www.datosabiertos.gob.pe/dataset/vacunaci%C3%B3n-contra-covid-19-ministerio-de-salud-minsa, which contains 7.3+ million rows, and used a slight variation of your code:

```
library(readr)
library(vroom)
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)
csv_file <- "vacunas_covid.csv.gz"
microbenchmark(
   readr={
     t <- read_csv(csv_file, col_types=cols())
     write_csv(t, csv_file)
   },data.table={
     t <- fread(csv_file)
     fwrite(t, csv_file, sep=",")
   },vroom={
     t <- vroom(csv_file, delim=",", show_col_types = F)
     vroom_write(t, csv_file, delim=",")
   },
   times=5
)
```

The results were:

```
Unit: seconds
       expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval  cld
      readr 101.72094 105.75384 109.16869 106.08111 108.06967 124.21788     5    c
 data.table  28.18751  30.32570  31.06592  30.44838  33.12746  33.24055     5  a
      vroom  48.65399  51.52445  55.78264  52.89823  53.83582  72.00071     5   b
```

From the results, `vroom` is at least 2x than `readr` using a big dataset, and `data.table` is ~1.7x faster than `vroom`. Perhaps the issue with the original example is that the data is small, and the indexing that `vroom` performs is contributing to the difference.

Just in case the code and results are at: https://gist.github.com/jmcastagnetto/fef3f3a2778028e7efb6836d6d8e3f8e